# How to return WorkflowInstanceId on CanCreateInstance on Receive Activity called via WCF

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-services

I am using Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0.

I have got a console app running a WorkflowServiceHost with an EndPoint defined for a Receive Activity at beginning of a workflow.

I can call this endpoint in my client app, and pass in some parameters, but I can't see a way of returning the WorkflowInstanceId to my client app.

Comment: Are you trying to do this to callback into the into the workflow to check status on a long-running operation?

Comment: Check Status, but also to then call subsequent Receive Activities I have in my workflow instance.
The WorkflowServiceHost will have many workflow instances running in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WorkflowInstanceId isn't exposed to the SendReply, or any other standard, activity by default. You need to create a custom CodeActivity and return the InstanceId from the context object passed in. Next you can store the ID returned in a workflow variable and return that from the SendReply.

Comment: Thanks Maurice, appreciate the response. Maybe something for future versions of WF as this would be common pattern I'm betting.

Comment: A lot of people tend to use a business key like an order number as workflow identifier. With correlation that works just fine. But that said, I do have a real simple actvity for this in my toolkit.